# How to make a floating guide for android apps?

Tags: android, documentation

I saw couple of apps that when I open them for the first time I get some floating windows that explain to me how to use the app.

I couldn't find any tutorials and code examples for this.
How do I make this kind of guide for my app?

Comment: Make a dialog with a WebView inside. Put some html file into the WebView, taken from the assets folder. That's all.

Comment: There's [an example of using ViewPager for this sort of thing](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) in the Graphics and Animation section of the Android docs.

Comment: This is not what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two projects that do exactly what I want

https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView

https://github.com/stephanenicolas/RoboDemo